# Logical operators in Closure Templates

Tags: javascript, google-closure-templates

I'm playing with [Google Closure Templates](https://developers.google.com/closure/templates/)
and I'm unable to successfully compile some templates because it seems that the logical "**and**" and "**or**" operators can't be used inside the if tag (I tried both "**&&**" and "**and**" and "**||**" and "**or**")... how can I write a "complex" if statements like: `{if condition1 && condition2}` ?

EDIT:

The following simple statement raises an exception:

**{if 5 > 2 && 2 == 2}**

**"Not all code is in Soy V2 syntax (found tag {if 5 > 2 && 2 == 2} not in Soy V2 syntax)"**

Comment: what exactly have you tried? `{if condition 1 && condition 2}` is no valid js.

Comment: that's the markup of Closure templates!

Comment: Well, that's weird: `and` and `or` are supported in Closure Templates. Could you show the whole expression instead?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to the latest version of the [docs](https://github.com/google/closure-templates/blob/3186e7624ccbe3aa01f20f0f55b3976cc2f617e1/documentation/reference/expressions.md#logical-operators-and-or-logical-operators), use can use **`and`** and **`or`** as logical operators:

```
{if $x > 1 and $y < 1}
   ...
{elseif $x < 1 or $y > 2}
   ...
{/if}
```

Comment: It is in the [docs](https://developers.google.com/closure/templates/docs/concepts#operators) newer version also suggest in the error message that the problem might be with `&&` or `||` usage.